# How do you compile libtasn1 with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, compilation, asn.1

I'm a new user of libtasn1 (trying to benchmark this library againts google's protobuf)....actually trying to be a new user....

I cannot make this library compile under Windows (using Visual Studio 2010).

Downloaded the latest version (4.2) from here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtasn1/
Then, I ran `configure` (had to install Cygwin first to have sh.exe, ar.exe....) from a Visual Studio 2010 command prompt. This apparently worked and outputed:

```
  version:          4.2 shared 9:2:3
  Host type:        i686-pc-cygwin
  Install prefix:   /usr/local
  Compiler:         gcc -std=gnu99
  Warning flags:    errors:  warnings:
  Library types:    Shared=yes, Static=yes
  Valgrind:
  Version script:   yes
```

And now, I cannot proceed to build. Here is what I tried:

Opened libtasn1.sln provided in the zip. First error reported config.h was not found (+ other header file). After updating include path I had more significant errors like C2054 on `inline static` in a few header files statements when compiling ASN1.c (which is C and `inline static` is not valid in C....).

I gave up here and tried to compile directly from the Visual command prompt by typing "nmake". It was short, got an error right away:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

makefile(269) : fatal error U1001: erreur de syntaxe : caractère non conforme '{' dans la macro
Stop.
```

Finally, I tried to compile with MinGW (using mingw32-make.exe). Same thing, got an error right away:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, /usr/bin/sed -n s/^\(sc_[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*\):.*/\
1/p ./maint.mk ./cfg.mk, ...) failed.
'test' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
make  all-recursive
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, make all-recursive, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
Makefile:928: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

libtasn1 web site says:

> The code should work on all Unix like operating systems, and Windows.

OK, but how to you build it? I could not find any information on the web site, nor in the INSTALL file...

Answer (score 0):

I'm running ubuntu linux 14.04

I used your link to download the newest ...gz file

I used a utility to unpack the file into `../Downloads/libtasn1/` which generated dozens of sub directories and files

I opened a normal command window
cd'd to the main directory: ../Downloads/libtasn1/libtasn1-4.2 then I read several files in that directory.
One of those files indicated that I should enter:
`./configure && make && make install`

I did as directed. the result was certain protected directories would not allow the insertion of new files

I opened a root command window
cd'd to the main directory: `../Downloads/libtasn1/libtasn1-4.2` then entered:
`./configure && make && make install`

a few minutes later, everything was successfully executed

Comment: Did you try that under Windows or Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .sln file in the windows subdirectory?

> This apparently worked

The key word here is "apparently". When you run `configure`, it examines the build environment and creates a makefile which is right for that environment. Since you ran configure with Cygwin's sh.exe, it created a makefile for the Cygwin environment (see the Host type: and Compiler: values). So even though `configure` created the missing `config.h`, the content is right for Cygwin with GCC, not Windows with MSVC.

`configure` creates makefiles that GNU make and many other Unix-y make programs can understand. Microsoft's nmake (when I last looked at it) understands a much more limited, and incompatible, language. You can't use a makefile created by `configure` with nmake.

For MinGW, have you tried using windows/libtasn14win.mk ?

Note: on the GNU FTP site for libtasn1, the lates Windows binaries are for version 3.3 :(

You might want to as on the help-libtasn1 mailing list for hints on how to create windows binaries. It is clear that the Windows build receives less attention than the rest of libtasn1.